# Does getId() return a unique value for similarly named views in different layouts?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a few different layouts, each with children that have the same view ID in the `xml` tag.

For example, `my_layout_one` contains a child view with the id `view1` and so does `my_layout_two`.

Will [`getId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()) return the same value if called on `view1` regardless of which of aforementioned layouts was inflated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `View` that has an `id` applied to it has a corresponding value in `R.java` class which is located at `app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/your/package` directory.

```
    public final class R {

        public static final class id {
            ...
            public static final int view1 =0x7f0d007e;
            // other view's ids
            ...

        }
    }
```

Regardless how many different `View`s you have declared in different layouts, all of those would have the same value in the `R.java` class assuming they have the same id applied in `xml` layouts.

[`View#getId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()) does nothing but returning the value from `R.java` class.

Answering to your question - yes, `getId()` would return the same id regardless which of those layouts was inflated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [azizbekian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43924607/5484290) answer i would also like to point out that, when you set your layout in any activity using `setContentView()`, that layout gets inflated and so all the top level views are added to the activity.
This is the reason that when you call `findViewById()` it returns the view from your activity's layout and not any other view having the same id in any other layout resource file.

So, obviously when you'll call `view1.getID()` it'll return view1 ID not view2. Although they have the same id, the android system will be checking for view1 only and not view2, as you have asked for this only.